# TextView выходит за границы экрана, перенос слов

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Здравствуйте!
Как правильно указать параметры width/height, чтобы Текст внутри TextView не вылазил за границы экрана и переносился на следующую строку?
Я уже пробовал мыслить разумно, затем взял бубен и это не помогло. Текст тупо выходит за границы и пропадает.Провобовал добавлять после присваивания 2й строчки "\n" и Текст в 3ей TextView переносился, но все еще не влазил. Еще: Текста много только в третьей TextView. В 1 и 2 в одну строчку всегда бует влазить, 5-6 символов там.
Есть мысля, что высота строки таблицы строится по параметру height первой ячейки.
Добавлено: 09,04,2013: Может нужно реализовать перенос по слогам? Как это вообще сделать возможно? 
Собственно код:

MainActivity:

```
TableLayout tab = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytable);
LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();

      while(cursor.moveToNext())
            {
        ...
        View item = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_items,tab,false);
            item.getLayoutParams().width=LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    TextView view = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tv_items); 
    TextView view2 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tv_items2);
    TextView view3= (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tv_items3);
    ....//тут я получаю инфу из SQLite курсором и загоняю в строку, затем SetText в TextView и cursor.close(); 
            }
```

Main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_for_views">
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/mytable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

view_items.xml:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_items"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_items2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_items3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: я подправил в veiw_items.xml 
дла каждого textview указал android:singleLine="false" и
xml третьего textView :
android:layout_height="wrap_content" и теперь переносит слова, но если слово длинное, то часть все равно пропадает, но следующее за ним начинается с новой строки.
Тем самым в лэндскейпе все хорошо, а вот в портретном режиме кривовато.

Comment: Попробуйте:

`<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">`

Comment: к сожалению нет.
стало вообще в одну строку.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="0, true">
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте вот это добавить к TextView

```
android:minLines = "1"
android:maxLines = "100"
android:singleLine = "false"
```

Comment: нет, тоже не выходит.
я даже добавлял еще один ТекстВью, 4ый, в виде линии. Но он игнорирует это и смещает его. Может нужно реализовать перенос по слогам?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так текст автоматически будет переноситься на следующую строку, даже будь это одно сплошное слово.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editDescr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="Description" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/etBlockText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="500dp"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"...
```

Все предыдущие варианты пробовал - не работают

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй так:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("тут необходимы тег переноса" + твоя_переменная + "закрытие тега переноса"));
```

Можно еще так:

```
String x;

    for(твой цикл получения данных) {
     x += твоя_переменная + "\n";
        }
       textView.setText(x);
```